# EF Code First lazy loading doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Consider the following entities:

```
public class MyEntity1 {
    public int ID {get; set;}

    public int MyEntity2ID {get; set;}
    public virtual MyEntity2 {get; set;}
}

public class MyEntity2{
    public int ID {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<MyEntity1> MyEntity1s{get; set;}
}
```

Inside the controller's create method for `MyEntity1` I go like this

```
// Create POST
UnitOfWork.MyEntity1Repository.Insert(myEntity1); // It contains a value for MyEntity2ID already
UnitOfWork.Save();

// Also tried this but still doesn't work:
// myEntity1 = UnitOfWork.MyEntity1Repository.GetById(myEntity1.ID);

myEntity1.MyEntity2.SomeProperty;  // MyEntity2 return nulls.
```

Why is this happening? is lazy loading only supposed to work when called on the razor view or something?

Comment: Where is your code that maps your model to your database? Maybe you missed your relationship in that mapping.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you're asking about the `DbContext`, I have `DbSet` for both entities.

Comment: You need to specify mappings which show how your entities relate to each other and also to the database. You can do this using attributes or using fluent notation in the OnModelCreating method. See this MSDN article for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking a POCO for a Entity Framework Proxy, they are not the same thing. The fact that EF requires the keyword `virtual` on properties to allow Lazy Loading should give you a clue on how EF does Lazy Loading.

Try new up a `DbContext` get a `MyEntity1` out and do `.GetType()` see what the ACTUAL type is.

So...now we have established that EF does NOT use your `MyEntity1` class, and created its own class which subclasses `MyEntity1`, how do we get a "new" of this subclass. The answer is to do `DbContext.MyEntity1s.Create();`.

Comment: You are saying that the problem here is that, since I'm using the same variable `myEntity1` (which is an instance of `MyEntity1`) to save and then read, it isn't a proxy. But when I do a `context.FindByID()` and assign it to a different variable, it returns the proxy subclass, and that's why it works?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco yes. The actual objects are actually different classes. The one that EF newed up has EF features like lazy loading, the one you inserted does not.

Comment: But then if I do something like `MyEntity1 me1 = context.FindByID(id)` I wouldn't be able to do `me1.MyEntity2`, but I am

Comment: What? What do you mean you "wouldn't be able to do `me1.MyEntity2`, but I am". The `MyEntity1Proxy : MyEntity1`. It overrides `MyEntity1.MyEntity2` with a null check and database call.

Comment: So the context would return a `MyEntity1Proxy` instance and assign it to **my** `MyEntity1` instance and that is the reason it works?

Comment: Ok, I just confirmed what you said by using the debugger, and to my surprise, **the entity giving me problem is NOT being instantiated as a proxy when I retrieve using context.FindByID()**. The other entities (which work fine) ARE proxies. Why is it happening?  I have that entity's DbSet in the context, along with the others

Comment: `DbSet.Find` will first search in its internal cache first before hitting the database. This is to ensure that a single context will only ever return a single copy of each entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring MyEntity2.MyEntity1s as virtual and make sure your table has appropriate fks defined.

Comment: It was already `virtual`, just noticed the mistake in my question. Also, I haven't defined any fks for any other of my entities, I'm just using the `[classname]ID` and `virtual` convention

Comment: Declare fks and pks and things should then work using the conventions that you're following.

Comment: Or declare them programmatically with entity framework attributes. The benefit of that is EF can generate your tables with proper pks and fks.

Comment: Ie like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319366/EF-Code-First-Add-a-Foreign-Key-relationship